# Rails 3 Times and for each another title

Tags: validation, controller, nested-attributes

I have problem with create good contorller or form.

I have models Feedback, Question and Rating
In table Question, I have five questions. And I would like to have rating each question in feedback.

Im using nasted attributes for feedback view .

My associaition - Feedback has many question through ratings.

My first idea was to create an appropriate feedback view:

```
    <% @questions.each do |q| %>
        <%= f.fields_for :ratings do |r| %>
            <%= q.question %>
            <%= r.hidden_field :question_id, :value => q.id.to_s  %>
            <%= r.number_field :mark %> <br />
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

But when I add any validations to form. Next I try cread non valid content I got form acting strange. Number of my answers grew from 5 to 25. And with each failed attempt, this number increased.

I think this is a better way, but I do not know him. Can you help?

Sorry for my English :)

My part of controller feedbacks:

```
      def new
        @feedback = Feedback.new()
        @questions = Question.all
        @feedback.ratings.build

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @feedback }
        end
      end

      def create
        @feedback = Feedback.new(params[:feedback])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @feedback.save
            format.html { redirect_to @feedback, notice: 'Feedback was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @feedback, status: :created, location: @feedback }
          else
            @questions = Question.all
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @feedback.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. Now i have guestions and for each question  form to put mark.

contorller:

```
      def new
        @feedback = Feedback.new(:complaint_id => params[:complaint_id])
        Question.all.each do |q|
          @rating = @feedback.ratings.build :question_id => q.id
          #@rating.question = q
        end
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.json { render json: @feedback }
        end
      end
```

view:

```
    <%= f.fields_for :ratings do |r| %>
        <%= getQuestion(r.object.question_id) %>
        <%= r.hidden_field :question_id %>
        <%= r.number_field :mark %> <br/>
    <% end %>
```